# OpenLayers GeoJSON

Tags: openlayers, json

I am trying to show some points. The coordinates are in the file 'test.json'.

But they wouldn't show themselves so I suppose there is something wrong with the code?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 80%;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
  </head>
<body>
    <h1>My Map</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'Global Imagery',
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
              params: {LAYERS: 'nasa:bluemarble', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
            })
          }),
          new ol.layer.Vector({
            title: 'Earthquakes',
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
              url: 'test.json',
              format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            }),
            style: new ol.style.Style({
              image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 10,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'red'})
              })
            })
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326',
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 0,
          maxResolution: 0.703125
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does test.json open as a valid layer in Qgis (or a similar gis)?

Comment: What is the CRS of test.json? Is it 'EPSG:4326' or another?

Answer (score 1):

Try running it without the style:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 80%;
        width: 100%;
      }

    </style>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.15.1/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers 3 example</title>
  </head>
<body>
    <h1>My Map</h1>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            title: 'Global Imagery',
            source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
              url: 'http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wms',
              params: {LAYERS: 'nasa:bluemarble', VERSION: '1.1.1'}
            })
          }),
          new ol.layer.Vector({
            title: 'Earthquakes',
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
              url: 'geojson/test.json',
              format: new ol.format.GeoJSON()
            }),
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          projection: 'EPSG:4326',
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 0,
          maxResolution: 0.703125
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If the layer shows, then maybe your style is the problem (ie your using the a point style for polygons), if it still doesn't work its probably the layer you are trying to load (is it in EPSG:4326? does it load in QGIS or similar?). The code works fine for me.